# Why is the tensor description of placeholder returned when using sess.run(placeholder, feed_dict)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(cost,feed_dict={z:logits,y:labels})

sess.close()

print(cost)
```

In the above snippet, it prints the tensor description 
**"cost = Tensor("logistic_loss_6:0", dtype=float32)"** rather than the value of cost.

However, if I use

```
sess = tf.Session()

cost = sess.run(cost,feed_dict={z:logits,y:labels})

sess.close()

print(cost)
```

then it outputs the cost.

My question is-  When I run the sess.run( cost, feed...), then isn't the cost evaluated and stored?

Answer (score 1):

One of the fundamental things to understand about Tensorflow is that it creates a computation graph that contains all operations. So in fact, the content of the variable `cost` is a tensor, which is an operation of the graph, that's why you get what you get, when printing it directly. In order to get the computation graph to actually compute something, you have to call `sess.run()` while feeding your inputs to the placeholders (which work as inputs to the Tensorflow computation graph), the `sess.run()` call then returns the computed value.

The call of `sess.run()` doesn't modify the graph, it only uses it to compute values of required tensors given inputs. So the answer to your question is: it is evaluated and the evaluated value is returned by `sess.run()` but **it is not stored** in the tensor. Think of tensors as symbolic pointers to the graph. The tensor just represents a node in the flow of computation in the graph, it never contains the evaluated value. You then use `sess.run(tensor, feed_dict)` to run the computation that is defined by your symbolic tensors, given inputs in the `feed_dict`. This is a core concept of Tensorflow, that's very important to understand.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on "Think of tensors as symbolic pointers to the graph"?